# Copying Mysql Data files from failed sd card

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

My raspberry pi isn't booting to the os.  It is getting stalled with various errors.  However I can open the sd card on another computer.  I want the data from mysql could I copy the datadir to another filesystem and once I have my pi working.  Copy those files to the new pi's datadir?

Comment: Just use the backup you made

Comment: I don't have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

**Very vague question**.

1. Pi can run different OS.
2. Different ways of storing data files by few versions of MySQL / MariaDB.
3. Copying datadir to **another file system**. Which FS?

**Now, probable solutions**.

1. Restore from backup. Should have taken backup (periodically).
2. Create a bootable SD for your Pi and place your datadir (of previous SD into the new SD. Do this after referring to
   https://serverfault.com/questions/659048/can-i-copy-the-entire-var-lib-mysql-folder-to-a-different-server-mysql-vs-mar
3. Before doing anything on the main Pi, do a dry run using yet another SD.